# Feature request: jump to page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Are the SF community planning on adding a jump to page functionality?
As of now, the Question --> Newest section consists of 2313 pages.
I can choose among the first five, next and last page. In no way can I easily navigate to page 1257.
Is this something more people here would like? Or is it here only that I'm missing it completely?

Comment: Not much help but, just enter the URL as serverfault.com/questions?page=1257 to jump to the page.

Comment: *Why* do you want to "easily navigate to page 1257"? Is there something special there? The page numbers are different for different people (depending on how many questions they show per page), and the contents of a given page change (as new questions come in). I'm having trouble envisioning why the feature would be useful...

Comment: Why don't you just use search?

Comment: On my part, it's simply about easy site navigation. Say I'm looking to improve the site by looking for old question and maybe answering them, it's more fun to just drop in on a random page. There is nothing more special about 1257 than 782, it's only about easy access. And ofcourse, it would have to be view-specific.

It's simply a suggestion. I don't frequently access page 1257, another reason this would be cool is because sometimes I like to just browse through the site, looking to learn. I could use the search function if I knew what I was looking for, but it's not always specific things.